# Have any chatbots fooled the judges and won the Loebner Prize Gold medal yet?

Tags: history, turing-test, chat-bots

I've read about The Loebner Prize for AI, which pledged a Grand Prize of $100,000 and a Gold Medal for the first computer whose responses were indistinguishable from a human's.

So I was wondering whether any chatbots have fooled the judges and won a Gold Medal yet?

From their [website](http://www.loebner.net/Prizef/loebner-prize.html) this isn't clear (as some of the links doesn't load).

---

A few highlights from previous years:

[2011 Loebner Prize results](http://loebner.exeter.ac.uk/results/)

> None of the AI systems fooled the judges, therefore the Turing Test has not been passed.

[Loebner 2013 results](http://www.paulmckevitt.com/loebner2013/scoring/loebner2013leaderboard.txt):

> No chatbot fooled any of the 4 Judges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 2016 finals haven't started yet, they will start on Saturday, 17 September 2016.

In the 2015 finals or before that, nobody won the Gold Medal or the Silver Medal. 
The most up-to-date data can be found [here](http://www.aisb.org.uk/events/loebner-prize), where we can find both the results from 2015 and the timeline of the 2016 contest.